problem with entering picture in Rmarkdown
I am using latex syntax since I am creating .pdf in RMardown to enter .png file in text.
title: "Untitled"
author: "Unnamed"
date: "2024-05-17"
output:
  pdf_document: default
  word_document: default
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```


```{r}

pckgs = c('readr', 'kableExtra', 'magrittr', 'tidyverse', 'ggplot2', 'ggpubr',
          'flextable','janitor', 'tidyr', 'readxl', 'car', 'effects', 'pastecs', 
          'compute.es', 'WRS2', 'multcomp', 'Hmisc', 'ggm', 'polycor', 'rstatix',
          'babynames', 'hrbrthemes', 'viridis', 'WRS2', 'googledrive', 'ppcor', 
          'lattice', 'lmtest', 'betareg', 'ggcorrplot', 'corrplot', 'RColorBrewer', 
          'glmmTMB', 'DHARMa', 'gtsummary', 'knitr')

sapply(pckgs, function(x){if(!require(x, character.only = T))
{install.packages(x);require(x, character.only = T)}
  else{require(x, character.only = T)}})


extxtxtxxtxtxt\textbf{Fig.~\ref{fig:figure1}}. 
```{r}
setwd("C:/all path to picture folder")
```

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{AA.png}
\caption{Fig 1: xxxxxxx}
\label{fig:figure1}
\end{figure}

But I am getting the following error.
A new version of TeX Live has been released. If you need to install or update any LaTeX packages, you have to upgrade TinyTeX with tinytex::reinstall_tinytex(repository = "illinois").
tlmgr.pl: Local TeX Live (2023) is older than remote repository (2024).
Cross release updates are only supported with
  update-tlmgr-latest(.sh/.exe) --update
See https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html for details.
! Package pdftex.def Error: File `AA.png' not found: using draft setting.

Errore: LaTeX failed to compile tr.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See tr.log for more info.

I am sure that AA.png is in the right folder. Do you know how I possibly could fix it?
Thanks

Is AA.png in the same folder as your rmd file?

Isn't there one code fence missing?

The setwd() command will have no effect on the LaTeX process that converts your document to PDF.  You should use knitr::includegraphics() if you want it to matter.  You should also read the error message, and follow its advice to update tinytex.

Thanks. Could please how (via code or site) I can update tynex ?

It says what to do in the first line of the error message!
